# how to change git path?

Tags: osx, path, git

So I just installed the latest git, with the official mac installer. I'm on Mavericks.

Sadly, git --version is still

```
git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)
```

and which git gives me:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

Instead, the git installer installed the updated git in

```
/urs/local/git
```

echoing $PATH gives:

```
[some hidden paths]:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin/:/usr/local/bin
```

How can I make my mac to use the right update git?

Comment: Change the order of your $PATH to search `/usr/local/git/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: Ok, but how (I'm not such an expert): for what I can see, $PATH is the union of several files, it's not stored on a single file. I think, among others, /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/git (this last containing /usr/local/git/sbin
)

Comment: Ok, in /etc/paths I had 
`/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin` and I added `/usr/local/git/bin` before all. Now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the older version of git in `/usr/bin/git`, the quickest and easiest thing to do is to rename the old binary in `/usr/bin/git` to something like `git.v1.9.3` and symlink the new version.

First rename:

```
mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git.v1.9.3
```

Next symlink new:

```
ln -s /usr/local/git /usr/bin/git
```

Now check the binary:

```
git --version
```

Comment: Operation not permitted on Sierra, should use https://stackoverflow.com/a/32661637

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
brew link --overwrite git
```